# javascript parseInt no esta funcionando

Tags: javascript

tengo una caden de texto en JS asi: JRAL630514... los numeros son AÑO MES  DIA de nacimiento, quiero 3 cajas de texto en php... sin problema con eso, mi problems es que necesito saber si pertence al los años 2000´s o 1900´s, y para eso necesito el prefijo '19' o '20'...y aqui esta mi problema uso la funcion parseInt con los 2 digitos del año pero me dice que es Nan...

```
var neim = document.getElementById("xrfcc").value;   <--- string : JRAL630514-pi9
var jsyir=  neim.substring(4, 6);
var nYir= parseInt(jsyir.value);
if( nYir >2004 ) {
    var prefijo='20';
} else {
    var prefijo='19';
}
var jsmont= neim.substring(6, 8);
var nMonth = parseInt(jsmont.value);
var jsdei=  neim.substring(8, 10);
  
elm["yir"].value = nYir;        <-- la caja en php textbox con ID= yir display NaN (not a number)
elm["mont"].value = nMont; <-- la caja en php textbox con ID= month display NaN (not a number)
elm["dei"].value = jsdei;
```

si uso jsyir, jsmont se despliega sin problema
que estoy haciendo mal??
Gracias

Comment: como validarías de que del texto `JRAL630514` esté entre el año 2000 o 1900? al hacer substring (del año) obtendrías `63` de la cadena... Por cierto, lo del error del NaN, quita los `.value` que tienes dentro del `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jsyir=  neim.substring(4, 6);
var nYir= parseInt(jsyir.value);
```

en estas dos líneas estas poniendole value a jsyir pero no lo necesita, creo que ese es el problema

```
var jsyir=  neim.substring(4, 6);
var nYir= parseInt(jsyir);
```